# SCP Fails - no error

Tags: scp

SCP has been working fine for a year or more and now nothing is being transferred but no error is captured either.

```
/home/users/temp_test . scp delete.me dest@target.com
```

ssh gives the following :

```
/home/users/temp_test . ssh dest@target.com
XXX Server supporting SFTP and SCP
This server does not support an interactive session.
Goodbye.
Connection to target.com closed.
```

Caveat - Not a Linux/Unix expert.  Server names & paths changed for privacy.

Comment: You are not specifiying a file path (check for a file named `dest@target.com` in current dir). Try `scp delete.me dest@target.com:` (note the colon at the end).

Comment: Ah - thank you - poor translation from the script to testing it manually!  The challenge is the customer says they are not receiving the files and I was attempting a manual check the connection at least was working (we were also not seeing any errors captured).  I was therefore confused that there was NO response when running scp on the command line.  And more confused when the -v option generated a file called dest@target.com!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written

> ```
> /home/users/temp_test . scp delete.me dest@target.com
> ```

I'm assuming that `/home/users/temp_test .` is the prompt, so can be completely ignored (the dot is confusing because it's a valid instruction in many shells). This leaves

> ```
> scp delete.me dest@target.com
> ```

Here, there is no remote path. You've two local files (in the current directory) called `delete.me` and `dest@target.com`. You can confirm this with `ls`. A remote path *must* contain a colon (`:`) to separate the [user@]host component from the path component.

Perhaps you meant this

```
scp delete.me dest@target.com:
```